# Create subdirectories using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a CSV file that includes custoomers informations, from it I'm able to create folders for each customers using the below script :

```
$Names = Import-Csv -Path “$PSScriptRoot\Info.csv” | Select-Object customer, info 

Set-Location -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Collection" 

foreach($customer in $Names) { 

$CustomerPath = '{0}{1}' -f $Customer.customer, $Customer.Info 

if (Test-Path -Path .\$CustomerPath) { 

$Message = '{0}{1} {2} exists' -f "`t", $Customer.Client, $Customer.Info 

Write-Message -Message $Message -ForegroundColor Green 

} 

else { $null = mkdir $CustomerPath 

$Message = '{0}{1} {2} created' -f "`t", $Customer.Client, $Customer.Info 

Write-Host -Message $Message -ForegroundColor Green 

}

}
```

My issues is that I'm not able to create subdirectories for each customers.
in other work I need to create some other folders into each customer folders that will receive files collections, for example CSV files [other data], excel files and so on...

structure should be :

customerFolder | CSV folder ESXCEL Folder DOC Folder

I already tried to modify my script above in order to create sub-directories without success.
as also I'm trying to use test-path in order to avoid to create the same folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in this code.

First you use the $Customer variable in two different contexts. I changed the reference in the ForEach loop to $Cust to eliminate this problem.

You're using formatting commands where simple string expansion will do.

While using PowerShell stick to PowerShell commands, i.e. New-Item vs MkDir.

I'd also suggest indention of your code structures to make reading easier.

NOTE: In the code below I changed your references to $PSScriptRoot to a fixed directory for testing purposes in the PowerShell ISE>

Input File:

```
Customer,Info
Mickey Mouse,Disney
Iron Man,Marvel
```

Code:

```
Clear-Host

$Names = Import-Csv -Path “G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Info.csv” | Select-Object customer, info 

Set-Location -Path "G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Test\Collection" 

foreach($Cust in $Names) { 

  $CustomerPath = "$($Cust.customer)$($Cust.Info)"  

  if (Test-Path -Path .\$CustomerPath) { 
    $Message = "Exists :`t $($Cust.Customer)$($Cust.Info)"
    Write-Host $Message -ForegroundColor Green 
  } 

  else { 
    $null = New-Item -Name $CustomerPath -ItemType Directory -Force
    $Message = "Created:`t $($Cust.Customer)$($Cust.Info)"
    Write-Host $Message -ForegroundColor Red 
  }

} #End ForEach
```

Sample Output: (color coding didn't show up when pasted)

```
Created:     Mickey MouseDisney
Exists :     Iron ManMarvel
```